# Unknown MySQL server host amazon rds

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I'm using linux command line to access amazon rds mysql, however, i keep getting the Unknown MySQL host error.

here is the command:

```
mysql -uxxx -pxxxx -hmydb.xxxx.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306
```

I have added MySQL rule in the security group, but it still does not work.

Comment: Problem solved. It seems the database needs a reboot after changing the MySQL rule.

Answer (score 12):

Or try:
mysql -u xxx -p xxxx -h mydb.xxxx.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com --port=3306